# How to set a JMS message property within JAX-WS handler?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, message-driven-bean

Is there any way to set a JMS message property within a JAX-WS handler?  I am trying to set a custom property on the message, to be used by a MDB message selector.

I've tried setting the properties on the SOAPMessage within a SOAPHandler, but that doesn't work so I think those properties may be at a different level that does not apply to the message selector.  And it doesn't work if I put the property in the BindingProvider's requestContext either.

Comment: you want to use soap over jms ?

Comment: Yeah, it's SOAP over JMS (using IBM's custom pre-packaged MDB).  So far I haven't found a way to set a property, and the MDB class might be the only place it can be done.  If that's the case, I'd have to replace the pre-packaged MDB with a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone reading this in the future: I was able to find a way to set JMS properties within a handler, but it appeared that the IBM generated MDB code was actually removing those properties.  You may have to ditch the JMSListenerMDB in order to solve this issue.